# cvs import: cannot make path to /opt/cvs/test_proj: Permission denied

Tags: linux, configuration, centos, checkout, cvs

I am using Centos 7.5
I installed cvs and cvs-inetd using yum
I followed the steps from https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/server/cvsserver.html

Started xinet services and all seems to work.
But when I try to create anew repository. It fails

```
$ cvs import -m "test repo" test_proj HEAD MAIN
I test_proj/test_proj/test.o
cvs import: cannot make path to /opt/cvs/test_proj: Permission denied
cvs import: failed to create lock directory for `/opt/cvs/test_proj' (/opt/cvs/test_proj/#cvs.lock): No such file or directory
cvs import: lock failed - giving up
cvs import: Importing /opt/cvs/test_proj/test_proj
cvs import: ERROR: cannot mkdir /opt/cvs/test_proj/test_proj -- not added: No such file or directory

No conflicts created by this import
```

The same error when I copied old CVS repo in to /opt/cvs and try to checkout.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: What are the ownerships and permissions of `/opt` and `/opt/cvs`?

Comment: @tink I created CVS group and gave the permission to all users. All cvs group has full access to /opt/cvs (not /opt). As a user I can cd /opt/cvs and create files inside it.

Comment: Are you sure? Try to "su" to whatever user serves your CVS service and try touching a file in that directory to be sure. If "su" won't let you at first, try "su -s /bin/bash <user>" and it should work.

Comment: It always let you to touch file or create folder when I ssh. Only option is to disable SELinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the exact root cause but the figured out something to do with SELINUX security. I turned off SELinux on `/etc/selinux/config`

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Then rebooted the server and all worked like a magic. Checkout and adding new repo works now. I am good with turning off the security for now. Since these components will be migrated to git and this server will be upgraded.
This solution is not recommended for anyone who is intended using CVS permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Permission is denied because the user you have logged in don't have the permission to create new file in `/opt/cvs/*` so just be a super user and perform the action like:

```
sudo cvs import -m "test repo" test_proj HEAD MAIN
```

Comment: I can create folder or file in CVSROOT location. What i did is ssh'd in to CVS server box and cd in to $CVSROOT and then created a folder. This is as the same user  asI am checking out.

Comment: @RamananT  check for permissions to the $CVSROOT directory.
cannot make path to /opt/cvs/test_proj: Permission denied: is because you don't have the permissions to create a file/directory.

Comment: figured out it is to do with SELinux

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @pranu_pranav disabling selinux solved the issue.